# Sketching phase portrait of an ellipse

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system of linear ODE's as follows:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = y, \frac{dy}{dt} = -4x$$

which has solution

$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = \alpha\begin{bmatrix}\cos2t\\-2\sin2t\end{bmatrix} + \beta\begin{bmatrix}\sin2t\\2\cos2t\end{bmatrix}$$

And I'm having some issues trying to sketch the phase portrait.

I know the eigenvalues are $-2i$ and $+2i$

Clearly this means the critical point $(0,0)$ is a "centre" of ellipses.

But I don't know how to find the indicative equation of one of the solution curves.

In other words, how do I find the shape of the ellipses? How do I know which of x,y is the major and minor axis of the ellipses?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
     \frac{d}{dt}\{ 4x^{2}+y^{2}\} = 8x\frac{d x}{dt}+2y\frac{dy}{dt}=8xy-8yx=0.
$$
Therefore, $4x^{2}+y^{2}=C$ is constant in time.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you did here.

Comment: @PythonNewb : What step do you not understand?

Comment: I don't get where that first equation for d/dt came from

Comment: @PythonNewb : The first equality comes from the chain rule. The second equality comes from your stated differential equations. The conclusion is that any solution $\left[\begin{array}{c}x(t) \\ y(t)\end{array}\right]$ of the differential equation must satisfy $4x^{2}+y^{2}\equiv C$ is constant, which is the equation of an ellipse.

Comment: How did you get to 4x^2 + y^2?

Comment: @PythonNewb : Experience. The 0 on the far right is because of dotting the tangent to the curve with the normal to the curve. For a circle you know what the tangent and normal must be. An axis-aligned ellipse comes from scaling one of the two coordinates; so you can adjust a little.